# HTTP Basic Authentication not working for resque-web on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque, authlogic

On [resque-web's GitHub page](https://github.com/resque/resque-web) it claims "HTTP Basic Authentication is supported out of the box. Simply set the environment variables `RESQUE_WEB_HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_USER` and `RESQUE_WEB_HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD` to turn it on. If you're using Resque with Heroku run heroku config:set `RESQUE_WEB_HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_USER=user` `RESQUE_WEB_HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD=secret` to get ResqueWeb secured."

I've done that. Here's what I get when I run `heroku config`:

```
RESQUE_WEB_HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD: mypassword
RESQUE_WEB_HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_USER:     resque
```

But when I visit `/resque` it works just fine; no authentication required to see everything.

Am I doing something wrong?

P.S. The only reason I'm using HTTP Basic Authentication is because I'm using Authlogic and the resque-web-Authlogic combo doesn't seem very well supported. This is kind of a last resort.

Comment: found a solution yet?

Comment: IIRC, I ended up needing to use the resque-web gem instead, and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone else is wondering, another way to implement HTTP authentication without needing to install the `resque-web` gem is by creating a `resque_admin.rb` file (or any other name) and putting the following code inside:

```
Resque::Server.use(Rack::Auth::Basic) do |user, password|
  user = "EnterUsernameHere"
  password == "EnterPasswordHere"
end
```

After you set these, everything else will work as normal.

Comment: add to `config/initializers`